# Passing data in angular 4 transitions name

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

Is it possible to pass data in an angular transition **name**?

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-supercharge-your-router-transitions-using-new-animation-features-v4-3-3eb341ede6c8) and basically I have the following code:

**Routes**:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  data: { page: 'home' }
 },
 {
  path: 'work-1',
  component: WorkOneComponent,
  data: { page: 'work-1' }
 },
 {
  path: 'work-2',
  component: WorktwoComponent,
  data: { page: 'work-2' }
 }
```

**App.component.html**

```
<div class="main-content" [@animRoutes]="getPage(appOutlet)">
    <router-outlet #appOutlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**App.component.js**

```
getPage(outlet) {
    return outlet.activatedRouteData['page'] || 'home';
}
```

**Animations**

```
export const animRoutes =
trigger('animRoutes', [
    transition('* => work-1', [...work animation here...]),
    transition('* => work-2', [...work animation here...]),
    transition('* => *', [...other animation here...])
]);
```

`Work-1` and `Work-2` have the same animation. Is it possible to have something like `transition('* => work-{{id}}', [..])`

Or, if not, maybe having a regular expression like this: `transition('* => ^work, [..])` ?

Thanks

***--EDIT--***

the person who wrote the Tutorial, Gerard Sans, [gave me an answer](https://medium.com/@gerard.sans/sure-you-can-achieve-this-by-using-something-like-2474bb06ff79).

```
// * => work-1, work-2, work-3, etc
const matchesWorkState = (fromState: string, toState: string): boolean => (!!toState && toState.toLowerCase().startsWith('work-detail-'));
export const animRoutes =
trigger('animRoutes', [
    transition( matchesWorkState, animWork),
    transition('* => *', otherAnim)
]);
```

note that in is answer, he wrote `transition( matchesWorkState(), animWork)` which is not working. Prefer `transition( matchesWorkState, animWork)` (without parentheses)

Comment: It should work. So unless you have another question or an issue ...

Comment: the way I write it doesn't work, I have the following issue:
The provided transition expression "* => work-{{id}}" is not supported

Comment: ... That's not what you wrote in your question ... Anyway, try with `'* => work-' + id`, but you're supposed to know the ID **when you build your application** so that's not dynamic, keep that in mind

Comment: Ok, I might have explain it wrong:
I have about 20 works, and I don't want to have 20 lines of:  `transition('* => work-1', workAnim),  transition('* => work-2', workAnim)...`.
If I use `* => work-' + id`, how can I get this id based on the routes data?

Comment: You can't. You have to write them in plain text. Or maybe use a wildcard, which is `*`, but I've never did that.

Comment: For those wondering, I asked the author of the tutorial and he gave me an exemple on how to achieve this. Check my question in the comments, there is an interesting answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comments and i little bit of thinking, I may have found a way to create all of your transitions at once.

Start with your routes :

```
export const routerTransitions = routes.map(route => {
  return transition('* => ' + route.data.page, [/* animations */]);
});
```

This will give you an array of transitions :

```
[
  transition('* => work-0', ...),
  transition('* => work-1', ...),
  transition('* => work-2', ...),
]
```

Now, you can use this array with a spread operator to declare your animations :

```
trigger('animRoutes', [
  ...routerTransitions
])
```

Comment: Really nice, bu I have the following error with your first code: `Cannot find name 'routes'.`. Where should I declare this variable?

Comment: In the same file where you declare your routes, or you have to import your routes variable

Comment: I actually found another answer gave by the person who wrote the tutorial: `const matchesWorkState = (fromState: string, toState: string): boolean => (!!toState && toState.toLowerCase().startsWith('work-detail-'));` and `export const animRoutes =
trigger('animRoutes', [
    transition( matchesWorkState, animWork),
    transition('* => *', otherAnim)
]);`

Comment: But it doesn't create an array of transitions like you asked, if you use that you will have to write 20 times the same code

Comment: No it's actually working perfectly as I want. I was not necessarily looking for an array, but more for "every states that start with work-" (work-1, work-2 etc... Since I also have other pages). But to come back to your answer, usually I declare routes in a constructor. But in the animation file I was not able to do so.